# Error Running "Jekyll Serve"

Tags: jekyll

Jekyll was working fine but I must have done something and caused below error. Searched other posts but don't see the answers.

Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

```
Edgars-MacBook:Site edgaryp$ jekyll serve
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you install the gem?

Comment: Yes I did Sebastiàn, the gem version 2.6.11. Output of `gem list`: `jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.2)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-paginate-category (0.1.2)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.0)
jekyll-watch (1.5.0)`

Comment: I don't see jekyll in the output, what about rails? bundle?

Comment: Yes bundle was missing so I have reinstalled again, not sure how did it happen but it's working now. Thank you very much Sebastián. If you want to command in the answer then I will defiantly tick it. Cheers.

Comment: Glad to help @edgaryp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see the output says `can't find gem jekyll (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)`

So according of what at least `gem list --local` says you must have the `jekyll` gem and all its main dependencies `jekyll-sass-converter` and `jekyll-watch`.

If you see them and not the `jekyll` one you may consider reinstalling it, or:

```
# if it is or exists
$ gem uninstall jekyll & gem install jekyll
```

Or also exists the possibility to download from Rubygems.org and install it, this if you want some specific version.

```
$ wget https://rubygems.org/downloads/jekyll-3.4.3.gem && gem install jekyll-3.4.3.gem
```